# Syntax Error in Python 3.2.1: Unable to write an exception to a ValueError

Tags: python

I'm new at python and recently I've been trying to write a code for a hangman game: a part of the MIT OCW course: Introduction to Computer Science and Programming. My code goes as follows:

```
def write_words (word, al):
    neww = (list(word))
    newal = (list(al))
    x = 0
    while (x <= (len(newal))):
        z = newal[x]
        y = neww.index(z)
        except ValueError:
            pass
        x = x + 1
        return (z)
        return (y)
```

when I call the function using `write_words ("word", "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy")` I still get the `ValueError:'a' is not in list`, that is supposed to be corrected with the exception. I 've been trying to figure out the problem, and apparently is a `Syntax error`. Please, I would be very grateful with any help. My python version is the 3.2.1

Comment: You seem to have your `return` statement inside the `while` loop with no conditions. That would return from the function in the first loop. Can you please explain what you are trying to do here?

Answer (score 4):

You don't have a `try` statement there. The format is `try-except`. Something like this.

```
try:
     a = 25 / 0
except ZeroDivisionError:
    print("Not Possible")


# Output: Not Possible
```